# C++ STL optimization warning: problem with the code or something more sinister?

Tags: c++, optimization, gcc, stl, vector

I have a program that I'm working on where I'm switching from using arrays to vectors, but I get a problem. I've reduced it down to this:

```
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
A(void);
~A(void);

private:
std::vector< std::vector<int> > a;
};

A::A(void) : a() {}

A::~A(void) {}
```

This gives the following warning from g++ (flags: -O2 -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations, version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) on Ubuntu 10.04 x86_64):

*/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_construct.h: In destructor ‘A::~A()’:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_construct.h:92: warning: cannot optimize loop, the loop counter may overflow*

So, what gives, Leo? Shouldn't the vector class keep track of how many elements it has? So, if that is the "counter" being referenced, how can it overflow?
(**Edit**: this question has more or less been answered below, but, to me, only leaves the corollary: why bother warning that a loop in the library can't be optimized? Why should I, the end user, be concerned with that?)

**Edit**:

Here is the relevent code being complained about (but, as I said in the comments, I don't see why that should be a consideration of mine as I shouldn't need to worry about the implementation of the library):

```
/**
 * Destroy the object pointed to by a pointer type.
 */
template<typename _Tp>
  inline void
  _Destroy(_Tp* __pointer)
  { __pointer->~_Tp(); }

template<bool>
  struct _Destroy_aux
  {
    template<typename _ForwardIterator>
      static void
      __destroy(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last)
    {
      for (; __first != __last; ++__first) // <-- this is line 92
        std::_Destroy(&*__first);
    }
  };
```

**Update**:

OK, I was anticipating one of either two answers: that I was doing something subtly abnormal (but not necessarily wrong) in *my* code, or that the message was very literally telling me that the loop pointed to in the library could not be optimized. Gratefully reassured that it was not the former, is reporting warnings from its own library expected behaviour from gcc, or should it be reported? (It doesn't seem worth opening another question to ask this so excuse this new questioning.)

**Update 2**:

OK, thanks for all the info guys: it's a bug in the compiler, then. Just for reference, I compiled an unmolested compiler and c++ library from GNU (version 4.5.2), which does not display this behaviour (the library code is identical), so I guess that warnings like this are not supposed to come up. Thanks again, everyone.

Comment: what purpose does the `: a()` serve in the constructor? does anything change if you remove it?

Comment: Well, I guess it might keep the pedants away! (unless I'm mistaken, which I may very well be...) No, still the same warning when I remove it.

Comment: Do you really need to use -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations? Isn't good old --funroll-loops good enough for you? And why no -O3?

Comment: No, no, and I'm allergic to three's. Look, I'm coming out in a rash already. Seriously though, I'm just curious: blindly continuing in the face of warnings is my speciality.

Comment: @Zorawar: and what if you copied here what's in `/bits/stl_construct.h` and identified the line `92` (note, only copying the function involved should be sufficient, no need to paste the whole header). It's a slight handicap of me: I am not clairvoyant.

Comment: @Matthieu: Well, this is what I'm really asking: is gcc complaining about my code or GNU's code? I shouldn't have to paste what's in bits/stl_construct.h because I should never have to worry about what's in there. Still, I'll add it in just in case I'm being stupid.

Comment: @Zorawar: you don't have to worry about what's in that file. The fact that you *do* is your own decision. The warning pretty clearly just says that it is unable to apply an optimization. That doesn't mean there's a problem with the code.

Comment: @jalf: Quoting myself: "but, as I said in the comments, I don't see why that should be a consideration of mine as I shouldn't need to worry about the implementation of the library". I asked the question so that I could find out from more knowledgeable people whether there was some mistake (or not doing something better, as the case may be, rather than an actual mistake) that I was making in _my_ code; it appears not, so I'm appeased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I finally got what the compiler was hinting at.

The loop is not executed on an integer, so I think what the compiler is trying to tell is that it cannot actually compute how many runs the loop will perform.

The warning you used should actually is usually coupled with `-funsafe-loop-optimizations`, from [gcc optimize options page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html):

> `-funsafe-loop-optimizations`
>       If given, the loop optimizer will assume that loop indices do not overflow, and that the loops with nontrivial exit condition are not infinite. This enables a wider range of loop optimizations even if the loop optimizer itself cannot prove that these assumptions are valid. Using  -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations`, the compiler will warn you if it finds this kind of loop.

I must admit I thought the compiler was always allowed to assume a loop would terminate eventually because deducing it would require solving the halting problem which cannot be solved in the general case.

But here, if you look at the function, it's impossible to prove that the loop will not overflow for a simple reason: the range `first` to `last` may be ill-formed.

- it could be that `first > last` (note: one cannot compare forward iterators)
- it could be that the alignments* are off, on pointers (`T*`) `++` is equivalent to `+= sizeof(T)`, and because a `!=` is used instead of `<`, `first` could jump over `last` if that is the case

Of course, it'll never happen in practice, because the library writers have ensured that they passed correct arguments to the method, but the compiler cannot deduce it, thus the warning.

Still I am surprised, I would have thought that compiler writers would purposely ignore the warnings raised by their own libraries because they had to employ those slight of hands just so that we don't.

(*) Not memory alignment here, I am merely hinting at the fact that a wrongly calibered `T*` could actually point within a `T` and that advancing `sizeof(T)` at a time would never actually allow it to ever settle back on a `T` boundary...

Comment: Yeah, it's odd that the compiler would tell the user _anything_ concerning the library because it's not the user's concern: why do I care if the compiler can't optimize _that_ loop? I was worried that there may have been something subtly bad (although not necessarily wrong) in _my_ code, but it seems not. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 6):

It just means the compiler cannot *prove* that it will not overflow.  Since you have -O2 on, you are asking for certain optimizations to be done for loops.  Some of these optimizations can only be done if these conditions can be proven.  The compiler warning you have asked for is telling you that some loops could not be optimized (I am guessing it is the inline destruction loop for the vector's underlying array probably.

You could disregard this warning I think.  However I do have to wonder why you asked for this warning in the compile options in the first place?

Comment: I asked just to be pedantic: I'll ignore this warning anyway since, as is my understanding, so what if it can't optimize? But, for such as basic situation as this, shouldn't gcc just chill out?

Comment: It does chill out if you don't ask it to display this warning ;)

Comment: But I want the reassurance that only a cold, heartless program can give, damn it! So, this is just a case of gcc complaining about its own library? (Or, perhaps, the library bemoaning the pedantry of its compiler.)

Comment: @Zorawar: did you read the warning GCC gave you? It is not "complaining about its own library". It is telling you "I am unable to do what you asked". You asked it to optimize loops and then you asked it to warn you if it finds any loops it can't optimize. And then it finds a loop it's unable to optimize, and, exactly like you asked it to, it warns you that it found a loop it was unable to optimize.

Comment: @jalf: I think I read it. But what's the point in telling me it can't optimize a loop that I shouldn't have to worry about?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is innocent.

The warning must be a fault of gcc compiler (at least, of the version you currently have) or the stl implementation they use. You should expect to get strictly no warnings about the correct code.